# Alternate to iPhone Configuration Utility for installing Certificates?

Tags: macos, iphone, ios

I need to install .cer certificate on iPhone to enable certain SSL connections to websites.

I have searched and found that this was possible using **iPhone Configuration Utility**, but that has been discontinued now.

Also tried using **Apple Configurator 2**, but I can not figure out how to install a .cer using it.

I am using iPhone 6S having iOS 9.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Apple Configurator 2, choose File → New Profile. Fill out the General section and add your certificate to the Certificates section. Connect your device and choose the profile you just created to apply to the device.